# Drupal / Server error request exceeded the limit of redirects due to probably configuration error

Tags: php, apache, drupal, redirect, dreamhost

Getting this error in my server logs, and 500 server errors on the site.  Sometimes it takes 30 seconds to load a page.  Any ideas?

```
[error] [client  71.35.150.139] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to  increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a  backtrace., referer:  beta/admin/modules/list/confirm?render=overlay
```

Comment: You're redirecting many times from page to page. Check your configuration and you will see that you build a never-ending-circle or something close to that.

Comment: I'm getting this on a new drupal installation on a wamp environment, while trying to begin the installation. It worked before, but not this time. It may be related with the updated apache version, from 2.4.2 to 2.4.4.